# Border Radius Issue in Chrome/Safari - Image is not clipping properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, safari

I have been in this particular issue for which i burnt almost 2 hours. I cannot figure it out and need a fresh perspective. I am uniquely facing bottom right border radius not showing up in chrome and safari.

I am using bootstrap carousel and using it to slide the image which is 100% width and has left margin of 10px and edges rounded on the top & bottom left using CSS

Here is the [link](http://supremeholdings.net/new/) for the demo i have uploaded. Any comment/suggestion/workaround will be appreciated. If you check it in IE10 or Mozilla you will find there is no issue

Comment: It's got something to do with your `height: 100%` on the `#carousel` element. When I remove this, I see the rounded borders in Chrome.

Comment: yup. seems to be the issue. I might just consider it as last option.. Thanks a bunch